# foundation zurb change font-size and full width

Tags: zurb-foundation

I use foundation 4 with SASS. but I can't really find how to change default font-size.
For my language, default font-size is too big.

I have tried to change some part. as you may know, it's related full-width as well.
1st of all I have changed full width size : $row-width: em-calc(1200) 
1000 to 1200. I need wider. is it correct way to change full-width?

I have tried to change font size.

```
$base-font-size: 100% !default;
$em-base: 16px !default;
```

When I change these. it's related full width.
Then How Can I change font-size and full-width? if you have sass, please let me know which file I need modified.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear what you are asking for in your question, but I hope I got it right - you want to know how to change the font without changing the grid size right?

Then the answer can be found in the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html):

```
/* Since the typical default browser font-size is 16px, that makes the calculation for grid size. */
/* If you want your base font-size to be a different size and not have it effect grid size too, */
/* set the value of $em-base to $base-font-size ($em-base: $base-font-size;) */
$em-base: 16px !default;
```

So basically just set:

```
@import "foundation/variables";
$base-font-size: 4px;
$em-base: $base-font-size;
```

Change the em-base back to the default and you'll see that the grid also changes accordingly to $base-font-size. You are also doing the right thing by setting the row-width.

If you'r having trouble getting the SASS function em-calc() to work, make sure you call it after `@import "foundation/variables";` I don't know why em-calc() is used in the documentation, maybe the sourcecode on [git](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/_variables.scss) is outdated - but I had to use emCalc(#px) - ie: `emCalc(2000px);`

Answer (score 0):

This is currently an issue, [Github repo](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2056).
Until it is fixed in a new version, this changes the font-size without changing the grid.

```
$base-font-size: 120% !default; // pixels to percent
body { font-size: $base-font-size; } // set the body font size to $base-font-size variable
```