# ZURB Foundation - How to change font sizes?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am confused about how to implement font-sizes in ZURB.

I have a page with:

Header:

> [2-col][2-col][2-col][2-col][4-col]

Main:

> [4-col][4-col][4-col]

The default font-size is 16px, but I would like the 'Header' type to be 21px. However, changing the `Header` font-size causes it to break out of the grid (I suppose it is affecting the width of the row somehow).

**How does one make the type bigger in the header without affecting the row width?**

I have made an [example jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/uSETen/2/) demonstrating the issue.

[image: **Screenshot of Problem**]

Comment: Hm, it appears I may have found the answer, which is forcing row width: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the correct scope (add `div.columns` in this case after div#nav):

```
div#nav div.columns {
   font-size: 21px;
}
```

If your using SASS take a look at my answer here: 
[foundation zurb change font-size and full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270651/foundation-zurb-change-font-size-and-full-width/19293665#19293665)

Comment: Ah yes. I see that I need to make sure not to alter the row style itself. Thank you!